# returning "Unable to find expo in this project - have you run yarn / npm install yet?" with eerything installed

Tags: node.js, expo

i already have done

```
yarn install
```

and

```
yarn global add expo-cli@3.27.14
```

which is the version of expo that the project uses.

But still always returning the same message:

> $ expo start
> ┌───────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────┐
> │                                                                           │
> │   The global expo-cli package has been deprecated.                        │
> │                                                                           │
> │   The new Expo CLI is now bundled in your project in the expo package.    │
> │   Learn more: https://blog.expo.dev/the-new-expo-cli-f4250d8e3421.        │
> │                                                                           │
> │   To use the local CLI instead (recommended in SDK 46 and higher), run:   │
> │   › npx expo                                                     │
> │                                                                           │
> └───────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────┘
> Starting project at /home/wallace-nascimento/Downloads/Dev-life/Pro/MyIO/react
> Unable to find expo in this project - have you run yarn / npm install yet?

Comment: Did you try to run "npx expo start"?

Comment: yes, i get the same result

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First I uninstalled the packages and then I reinstalled the latest version of expo.

```bash
npm uninstall -g expo-cli
```

Then:

```bash
npm install -g expo-cli@latest
```

`@latest` will download the latest version of the package `expo-cli`.

Comment: But as i said, i need to use this version of expo, cause is the version all the app uses. and anyway, i tried to do that, and the error keeps happening

Answer (score 0):

run PowerShell as administrator, if you are using a terminal in VScode then run VSCode as administrator, if it still doesn't work then type "Set-ExecutionPolicy" in PowerShell and "unrestricted" the scripts, best of luck